# accessoryType randomly disappeares at rows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Goodmorning SO,

i got this problem for like a whole week now and so weird.

i got a table filled with VM's which i can turn on/off/reboot etc.. and each row has a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`
when i send an action to a VM, i check every 3 seconds if the action has been succesfully done while waiting the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` is replaced by a activity indicator.When an action is done the row that the VM is in should refresh, this works fine.
but the problem is that sometimes.. realy sometimes the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` doesnt comes back when a VM is done and there is no accessoryType annymore for a row.This is just in a randomly row that i send a action to...
lets say i got 5 rows.

```
X*    
X*
X*
X*
X*
```

(`X` = row, `*` = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton)
and i turn on all of them then this happens

```
X 
X
X*
X*
X
```

then at random places the UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton disappeares and doesnt comes back untill i reopen the whole UIView.

Why is this?
Here is some code.

```
[activityView stopAnimating];
[timer invalidate];
NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:TheindexPath(This is the indexpath of the row where an action should be done.)];
[TheTableWithMachines reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[activityView release];
```

in the

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

i even check if a cell has a button or not if not.. add it

```
if(cell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }
```

I got it finally fixed after looking around alot!

The activity indicator was a AccesoryView and the UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton was the AccesoryType of the cell i just needed to set this [cell setAccessoryView:nil]; at the end of the code

But i still dont know why UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton sometimes did disappeared.

annyway it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [hidesWhenStopped](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)  property of UIActivityIndicatorView